# Solving complex equation: $(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

We're supposed to solve this complex numbers equation:

$(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2 = 0$

I'm getting the result:

$z_{1} = \frac{1-i}{2}, z_{2} = \frac{1+i}{2}$

Others are getting the same result. However, the answers page says that the result should be:

$z_{0} = - \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{5}i$

Would anyone be able to give it a look and verify whether I am wrong or the answers page is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the work you did to get the results you report that you obtained.  Expand the equation, and show us your work in determining $z_1, z_2$.  Whether the results are correct or not isn't as important, and can't be substituted, for how you obtained them.  Furthermore, adding your work, in the event that you are wrong, will help us help you identify where your mistake may have been.

Comment: You can plug in your numbers to show that $(1-i)/2$ and $(1+i)/2$ do not satisfy the original equation, and hence are not the solutions. I would probably set $z=a+bi,$ with $a$ and $b$ real, and solve the two equations simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for the complex equation below is the proof:
$(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2 = 0  \Rightarrow z^2+1-2z+\bar{z^2}-4-4i\bar{z}=0$ 
We know $z^2+\bar{z^2}=2 \Re{z^2}=2x^2-2y^2$ where $z=x+iy$ and $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Substituting $z=x+iy$ in the complex equation we get $2x^2-2y^2-3-2(x+iy)-4i(x-iy)=0$. So both real and imaginary parts of the resultant equation must be zero. So we get:
$$2x^2-2y^2-2x-4y-3=0$$
and
$$-2y-4x=0 \Rightarrow y=-2x$$
Substituting $y=-2x$ into the first real equation we get
$$2x^2-8x^2-2x+8x-3=0$$
or$$-6x^2+6x-3=0$$
or $$x^2-x+0.5=0$$
so $$x=\frac{1\pm i}{2}$$ which is not a real number. So there will not be any real $x$ and $y$ satisfying the complex equation. Therefore no complex $z$ satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 1):

$z=\frac{-3+6i}{10}$ is not a solution to this problem. Let's make sure.

$z-1=\frac{-13+6i}{10}$,

$\bar{z}-2i=\frac{-3-6i}{10}-\frac{20i}{10} =\frac{-3-26i}{10}$

$$(z-1)^2=\frac{(-13+6i)^2}{100}=\frac{169 - 156i-36}{100}=\frac{133-156i}{100}$$

$$(\bar{z}-2i)^2 =\frac{(-3-26i)^2}{100}=\frac{9-156i-676}{100}=\frac{156i-667}{100}$$

So therefore $(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2=-5.34$

In fact, there are not solutions to [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(z-1)%5E2%2B(Conj(z)-2i)%5E2%20%3D%200) equation.

It's not that hard to see if you apply $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$
Taking $a=z-1$ and $b=\bar{z}-2i \implies bi= \bar{z}i+2$

$a+bi=z-1+\bar{z}+2=z+\bar{z}+1$ and

$a-bi=z-1-\bar{z}-2=z-\bar{z}-3$ and

We arrive at

$(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2=(z+\bar{z}i+1)(z-\bar{z}i-3)=0$

Taking $z=a+bi \implies \bar{z}=a-bi\implies \bar{z}i=b+ai$

So then $z+\bar{z}i=(a+b)+(a+b)i$ and $z-\bar{z}i= a-b-(a-b)i$
What's note worthy here is that the real and the imaginary parts of these numbers are the same.

Then $z+\bar{z}i=-1 \implies a+b+(a+b)i=-1$ but then $a+b$ is simulataneously $0$ and $-1$ and likewise $z-\bar{z}i=3\implies a-b-(a-b)i=3$ implies that the $(a-b)$ is simultaneously $3$ and $0$.

So we conclude: No solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to arrive to the conclusion that the equation has no solutions:

Write  $\;z=a+bi\implies\overline z=a-bi\;$ , and the given equation is

$$(a-1+bi)^2+(a-(b+2)i)^2=0\iff$$

$$(a-1)^2-b^2+2(a-1)bi+a^2-(b+2)^2-2a(b+2)i=0$$

and compare now real and imaginary parts:

$$\begin{cases}(a-1)^2-b^2+a^2-(b+2)^2=0\iff2a^2-2b^2-2a-4b-3=0\\
2ab-2b-2ab-4a=0\iff b=-2a\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies$$

$$2a^2-8a^2-2a+8a-3=0\iff 6a^2-6a+3=0$$

adn the last equation has no *real* solution...as it should if there was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I think worth mentioning it:

You can write the expression as difference of squares and factor it into two factors which can never be $0$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}(z-1)^2+(\bar{z}-2i)^2 & = & (z-1)^2-i^2(\bar{z}-2i)^2 \\
& = & (z+1 + i\bar z)(z-3 - i\bar z) \\
& = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$
With $z = a+ib$ you get

- $z+1 + i\bar z = a+b+1 + i(a+b) \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Rightarrow \mbox{No solution!}$
- $z-3 - i\bar z =a+b-3 + i(a+b) \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Rightarrow \mbox{No solution!}$